# I did the shoes selling website for my assignment but I cant connect to my database for my website

Tags: python, html, xampp

```
`        <div class="payment">
            <h1 class="payTitle">Personal Information</h1>
            
                <form action="checkout.py" method="post">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Johan Dee" class="payInput" id="name" required><br>
    
                <label for="PhoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
                <input type="text" name="PhoneNumber" placeholder="+60 12 345 6789" class="payInput" id="PhoneNumber" required><br>
    
                <label for="address">Address</label>
                <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="No 1, Jalan Mawar, Senawang, Negeri Sembilan" class="payInput" id="address" required><br>
    
                <h1 class="payTitle">Card Information</h1>
                <div class="cardIcons">
                <img src="./img/visa.png" width="40" alt="" class="cardIcon">
                <img src="./img/master.png" alt="" width="40" class="cardIcon">
            </div>
    
                <input type="password" name="CardNumber" class="payInput" placeholder="Card Number" id="CardNumber">
                <div class="cardInfo"> 
                <input type="text" name="month" placeholder="mm"  id="month" class="payInput sm">
                <input type="text" name="year" placeholder="yyyy" id="year" class="payInput sm">
                <input type="text" name="CVV" placeholder="cvv" id="CVV" class="payInput sm">
    </div>
    
    <button class="payButton" type="submit">Checkout!</button>
    <span class="close">X</span>
```

so this is my html file for the interface and i want the "checkout!" button to inserted the data to my database

so this is my python code for the process:

```
`#!C:/python311/python`
`print("Content-type: text/html")`
`print()`

`import cgi`

`form=cgi.FieldStorage()`

`name=form.getvalue("name")`
`PhoneNumber=form.getvalue("PhoneNumber")`
`address=form.getvalue("address")`
`CardNumber=form.getvalue("CardNumber")`
`month=form.getvalue("month")`
`year=form.getvalue("year")`
`CVV=form.getvalue("CVV")`

`print("name: ", name )`
`print("`<br>`")`
`print("PhoneNumber: ", PhoneNumber)`
`print("`<br>`")`
`print("address: ", address)`
`print("`<br>`")`
`print("CardNumber: ", CardNumber )`
`print("`<br>`")`
`print("month: ", month)`
`print("`<br>`")`
`print("year: ", year)`
`print("`<br>`")`
`print("CVV: ", CVV)`
`print("`<br>`")`
`print("...From form HTML and Python")`
`print("`<br>`")`

`import mysql.connector`

`conn=mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', host='localhost', database='mydb3')`
`print(" -Database connected- ")`
`cursor=conn.cursor()`
`cursor.execute('insert into personal_information values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)',(name,PhoneNumber,address,CardNumber,month,year,CVV))`
`conn.commit()`

`cursor.close()`
`conn.close()`

`print("`<br>`")`
`print("-Record inserted successfully- ")``
```

but sadly it still didn't successfully inserted the information into the database, even the table name columns are similar. so I don't know what's the problem. btw i use phpmyadmin for my assignment

I did what ChatGPT told me to use to insert apostrophe and it still didn't work and most of the ChatGPT suggest also didn't work

Comment: ChatGPT is not an expert on HTML or Python

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.